How to forward the notification from one device to another use fcm
I wan't to create an app that can forward the notification from one device to another using fcm.
The app will run on one device and listen the notification by NotificationListenerService as server, and now I can read the notification that posted on this device, but it seems it can not succeed in posting the notification info use Firebase Admin SDK.
I'm sure I can successful send the notification on another device as client, for I've tested using the offical tool on the Firebase control panel.
Firebase control panel
Here is my part of code:
override fun onNotificationPosted(sbn: StatusBarNotification?) {
    super.onNotificationPosted(sbn)

    val notifatication = sbn?.notification;
    val extras = notifatication?.extras;

    var extraImage = extras?.getString(Notification.EXTRA_PICTURE)
    val title = extras?.getString(Notification.EXTRA_TITLE, "")
    val body =
        extras?.getCharSequence(Notification.EXTRA_TEXT, "").toString()

    val token = sharedPreferences.getString("Token", "")

    if(!token.isNullOrEmpty()){
        Log.d(TAG, "send to $token")

        val msgId = AtomicInteger()
        val RMBuilder = RemoteMessage.Builder("$token@gcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send")
        RMBuilder.setMessageId(msgId.incrementAndGet().toString())
        RMBuilder.addData("title", title)
        RMBuilder.addData("body", body)

        // Send a message to the device corresponding to the provided
        // registration token.
        val response = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().send(RMBuilder.build())
        Log.d(TAG, "result is $response")
    }
}

Here is my full code:
(https://github.com/HappyMax0/NotificationSync)
I've tried the Firebase Admin SDK, or is there any other way to send notifications use fcm?

It is not possible to securely send messages through FCM directly from one device to another. Sending a message to device requires that you specify administrative credentials, and including such credentials in your client-side application code would mean that a malicious user can take them and send any message they want to any of your users. Sending a message to a device, must always be done from a trusted environment.
